# An intuitive way to express Lagrange theorem.

Tags: group-theory

Is the below an intuitive way for stating Lagrange theorem? If not, where it lacks.

In case of cyclic groups, whole group can be generated by one element (any) in group by repeated application. Hence, there can be at minimum one partition for entire group. While for acyclic groups (disjoint set of actions, so that no element in the group can be generator of the entire group) there would be at least as many partitions by disjoint sets, as there are disjoint cycles in the group table.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio The Algebraic explanation hides the basic understanding that it is based on two different criteria for cyclic and not - cyclic graphs.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Please tell where wrong, please take example if possible.

Comment: It seems not too much to expect a reason.

Comment: @jiten: The issue seems to be that you haven't asked a question, and therefore no one can offer an answer. (This is problematic on a question-and-answer site. ;) Perhaps you should preface your description with something like *"Is the following a valid intuitive explanation of Lagrange's Theorem?"*

Comment: The assertions in post are incomprehensible and as far as I'm concerned that's all there is to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intuition is that if $G$ is a finite group and $H \leq G$, then $|H|$ divides $|G|$.

The proof is basically that the left-regular action ($H$ acts on $G$ by left-multiplication) partitions $G$ into orbits of size $|H|$.

Comment: Seems that right application of $H$ to $G$ should also be valid. If not, why?

Comment: The property of group $H$ being $\leq$ to another group $G$, is not clear. Does it also mean that  $H$ is a subgroup of $G$?

Comment: Yes- the right action also works. And $\leq$ denotes the subgroup relation.